# How to convert dataframe to nested dictionary with specific array and list?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

How can I use a dataframe to create a nested dictionary, with interleaved lists and columns, as in the example below?

**Create dictionary**:

```py
columns = ["name","reason","cgc","limit","email","address","message","type","value"]
data = [("Paulo", "La Fava","123456","0","p@p.com.br","avenue A","msg txt 1","string","low"), ("Pedro", "Petrus","123457","20.00","pop@petrus.com.br","avenue A","msg txt 2","string", "average"), ("Saulo", "Salix","123458","150.00","python@salix.com.br","avenue B","msg txt 3","string","high")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df.show()
```

**expected outcome**

```json
{
    "accepted": [
        {
            "issuer": {
                "name": "Paulo",
                "reason": "La Fava",
                "cgc": "123456"
            },
            "Recipient": {
                "limit": "0",
                "email": "p@p.com.br",
                "address": "avenue A"
            },
            "additional_fields": [
                {
                    "message": "msg txt 1",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "low"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in Spark are homogeneous i.e. the elements should have same data type. In your sample expected output, the array type of "additional_fields" does not match with other two map fields "issuer" & "recipient".

You have two ways to resolve this:

If you can relax "additional_fields" to be just the map (not array) like "issuer" & "recipient", then you can use following transformation:

```py
df = df.withColumn("issuer", F.create_map(F.lit("name"), F.col("name"), \
                                          F.lit("reason"), F.col("reason"), \
                                          F.lit("cgc"), F.col("cgc"), \
                                         )
                  ) \
       .withColumn("recipient", F.create_map(F.lit("limit"), F.col("limit"), \
                                             F.lit("email"), F.col("email"), \
                                             F.lit("address"), F.col("address"), \
                                            )
                  ) \
       .withColumn("additional_fields", F.create_map(F.lit("message"), F.col("message"), \
                                                     F.lit("type"), F.col("type"), \
                                                     F.lit("value"), F.col("value"), \
                                                    )
                  ) \
       .withColumn("accepted", F.array(F.create_map(F.lit("issuer"), F.col("issuer"), \
                                                    F.lit("recipient"), F.col("recipient"), \
                                                    F.lit("additional_fields"), F.col("additional_fields"), \
                                                   ))
                  ) \
       .drop(*[c for c in df.columns if c != "accepted"] + ["issuer", "recipient", "additional_fields"])
```

or, if you want to make "issuer" & "recipient" field types similar to "additional_fields" then use:

```py
df = df.withColumn("issuer", F.array([F.create_map(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in ["name", "reason", "cgc"]])) \
       .withColumn("recipient", F.array([F.create_map(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in ["limit", "email", "address"]])) \
       .withColumn("additional_fields", F.array([F.create_map(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in ["message", "type", "value"]])) \
       .withColumn("accepted", F.array([F.create_map(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in ["issuer", "recipient", "additional_fields"]])) \
       .drop(*[c for c in df.columns if c != "accepted"] + ["issuer", "recipient", "additional_fields"])
```

Comment: I managed to take a few steps. But I still can't PUT into the API because of the "additional_fields" field. Is there any way around homogeneity?

I did some tests, trying to create the array before the map, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: You will have to construct "accepted" field outside Spark in Python array while calling API.

Comment: I used the for loop to update another dict, then loaded it into a list and finally into the main dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I used the for loop to update another dict, then loaded it into a list and finally into the main dictionary.

```
coll = df.collect()
main = {}
main["main"] = lst
lst = []
lst.append(dict1)
dict1 = dict(dicta, **dictb)
dict1 = {}

for row in coll:
  print(row['accepted'])
  dicta = row['accepted']
  print(row['additional_fields2'])
  dictb = row['additional_fields2']
  dict1.update(dicta)
  dict1.update(dictb)
```